# html5 custom control not work if multiple video

Tags: javascript, button, video, html5-video

I'm trying to make a custom video player. Unfortunately, I have an issue to set the control to all videos. The control button is working well, but only on the first video. I would like to make it without adding all video unique IDs. Is that even possible?

Here is my code:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('.video');
const btn = document.getElementById('play-pause');
const sound = document.getElementById('volume');

sound.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  video.muted = !video.muted;
  sound.classList.toggle('mute');
});

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
  btn.classList.toggle('pause');
});
```

```css
.container {
  background:#ccc;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
/*   height:100vh; */
  flex-direction:column;
}
.c-mst-video-container , .video {
  width:100%;
}
.mst-video-container {
  max-width:800px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}
.mst-video-container:hover .controls {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.mst-video-control {
  display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background-color: black;
}
.mst-video-btn button {
  background:none;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.mst-video-btn #play-pause:before {
  content: '\f144';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
  color: #fff;
}
.mst-video-btn #volume:before {
  content: '\f028';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mst-video-btn {
  padding:10px;
  
}
.mst-video-btn #play-pause.play:before {
  content:'\f144';
}
.mst-video-btn #play-pause.pause:before {
  content:'\f28b';
}
.mst-video-btn #volume.sound:before {
  content:'\f028';
}
.mst-video-btn #volume.mute:before {
  content:'\f6a9';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="mst-video-container">
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" class="video" ></video>
    <div class="mst-video-control">
      <div class="mst-video-btn">
        <button id="play-pause"></button>
        <button id="volume"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="mst-video-container">
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" class="video" ></video>
    <div class="mst-video-control">
      <div class="mst-video-btn">
        <button id="play-pause"></button>
        <button id="volume"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the advice.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use a class .play-pause instead than #play-pause and attach a listener to all the buttons. Furthermore, when a button is clicked you have to select the video and you have to navigate and I used `closest()` to select the container of the btn clicked and querySelector not on the document but on this container to select the .video child. `e.target` return the btn clicked, in this case you can't use `this` because you are using an arrow function. I modified the css too transforming the id #play-pause in a class.

```js
const video = document.querySelector('.video');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.play-pause');
const sound = document.getElementById('volume');

sound.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  video.muted = !video.muted;
  sound.classList.toggle('mute');
});

for(const btn of btns){
btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  const currentBtn = e.target;
  const videoContainer = currentBtn.closest(".mst-video-container")
  const videoParent = videoContainer.querySelector(".video");
  videoParent.paused ? videoParent.play() : videoParent.pause();
  currentBtn.classList.toggle('pause');
});
}
```

```css
.container {
  background:#ccc;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
/*   height:100vh; */
  flex-direction:column;
}
.c-mst-video-container , .video {
  width:100%;
}
.mst-video-container {
  max-width:800px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}
.mst-video-container:hover .controls {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.mst-video-control {
  display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background-color: black;
}
.mst-video-btn button {
  background:none;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.mst-video-btn .play-pause:before {
  content: '\f144';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
  color: #fff;
}
.mst-video-btn #volume:before {
  content: '\f028';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mst-video-btn {
  padding:10px;
  
}
.mst-video-btn .play-pause.play:before {
  content:'\f144';
}
.mst-video-btn .play-pause.pause:before {
  content:'\f28b';
}
.mst-video-btn #volume.sound:before {
  content:'\f028';
}
.mst-video-btn #volume.mute:before {
  content:'\f6a9';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="mst-video-container">
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" class="video" ></video>
    <div class="mst-video-control">
      <div class="mst-video-btn">
        <button class="play-pause"></button>
        <button id="volume"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="mst-video-container">
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" class="video" ></video>
    <div class="mst-video-control">
      <div class="mst-video-btn">
        <button class="play-pause"></button>
        <button id="volume"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```